# Firebase: Unable to get permission to notify. FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am unable to get the token in Edge.

The code works in:

- Chrome
- Firefox

but does not work in:

- Edge

In console log I get a message `Notification permission granted.` but not the token. Here is code:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
};
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.requestPermission()
    .then(function() {
      console.log('Notification permission granted.');
      return messaging.getToken();
    })
    .then(function (token) {
      console.log(token)

    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
    });
```

Comment: @NomanAli But Edge Browser Supports Push Notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edge support for notification API](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/05/16/web-notifications-microsoft-edge/) just like you [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46948267/firebase-unable-to-get-permission-to-notify-firebaseerror-messaging-this-bro#comment80844868_46948267) but it doesn't support [Push API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=push-api) yet. Their Push API implementation is [still under development](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/pushapi/?q=push).

Note that notification API allow your website to show a message while it still opened in background or idle but Push API is the one can push message from server even if the user is not currently opening your website.

Comment: Can you suggest me any alternative to fix this. I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging  for messaging and Notifications

Comment: While I don't know your requirement why you want to support for offline push notification in `Edge`, you can still show `offline notification not supported` to `Edge` user if you want. However you can still send online notification whenever your website opened via `Notification API`. You just need to implement it in `JavaScript` + `WebSocket` manually or probably try `FCM` using [`XMPP`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message)